# How do the Ghostbusters afford their Ghostbusting apparel?

Tags: weapon, ghostbusters

I know that Ray remortgaged his parents' house to afford everything - renting the fire house, the car… 4 Cyclotron particle accelerators!

How does one man afford all that?

What does remortgaging a house in 1984 get you, and how much do particle accelerators cost?

Comment: I could be wrong but didn't the scientist Egon have patents for inventions and sold them or something to that effect?

Comment: @DoctorWho22 I'm not sure about that, I couldn't see it on the wiki.

Comment: They are not purchased they are built [ref](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Proton_Pack)

Comment: As James Jenkins said, while most of the things they got were from the re-mortgaging of the house, the proton packs were an original construction - probably a crazy expensive reconstruction, but considering how little they paid for all their other gear, they may have been able to afford it.  Especially if, like everything else, half of it worked on a hope and a prayer.

Answer (score 10):

> What does remortgaging a house in 1984 get you

Potentially quite a lot, if Ray's parents owned it with no mortgage, and it was in a desirable area in or near New York City. In today's money, [median price of a home in Long Island](http://www.trulia.com/real_estate/Long_Island_City-New_York/market-trends/) is $610,000 and [Manhattan townhouses](http://www.townhouseexperts.com/PropertyList.asp?area=new) start at $3M. In 1984 New York was experiencing a [house price boom](http://furmancenter.org/files/Trends_in_NYC_Housing_Price_Appreciation.pdf) which would peak in 1989-90.

House prices have increased much faster than general inflation (see previous link) and in 1984 they were very roughly 25% of modern values, but even so they would have had at least $150,000 in today's money and possibly much more. As Zibbobz points out, they tried to cut all possible corners on their other expenses:

> RAY: Everybody can relax, I found the car. Needs some suspension work and shocks. Brakes, brake pads, lining, steering box,
> transmission, rear-end.
>
> PETER: How much?
>
> RAY: Only $4800.
>
> [Peter looks shocked]
>
> RAY: Also new rings, mufflers, a little wiring.

And regarding the derelict firehouse:

> EGON:  I think this building should be condemned. There's serious
> metal fatigue in all the load-bearing members, the wiring is
> substandard, it's completely inadequate for our power needs, and the
> neighborhood is like a demilitarized zone.

So they must have had a fair amount of money left over for equipment.

> how much do particle accelerators cost?

In the case of the Ghostbusters' customized equipment, it wouldn't be for sale at any price. Do you think "ghost containment facility" appears in a lab supplies catalog? For the most part, they would have had to build it themselves.

This isn't explicitly stated, but it is very likely they were able to scrounge/steal parts and supplies from the university lab before they were fired. The university scenes take place at Columbia which is a fairly well-funded institution.

Comment: On the cost of building a small cyclotron accelerator, the article at http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/august-2010/the-do-it-yourself-cyclotron estimates it would cost about $125,000 for the parts (and that's in 2010 dollars, that would be about $60,000 in 1984 dollars according to the inflation calculator at http://www.bls.gov/data/inflation_calculator.htm ) The article also notes that this is if you buy all the parts new, the people profiled were able to build theirs significantly cheaper by finding used parts.

Comment: This a great answer, but it seems like people might miss components to a particle accelerator ... I don't know. Can you reference the stealing part?

Comment: @hypnosif that would clinch it! Great find wow, far cheaper than I expected

Comment: @Pureferret: They might not miss the parts, especially if they were from items considered old, broken or obsolete. I don't have a reference for the stealing, but Venkman in particular was, shall we say, less than ethical in his research practices. As Venkman himself might say, "What are they going to do, fire me?" :-)

Comment: They might even have built the items legitimately with university funding. "Can we take our custom equipment with us?" "Yeah, whatever, just get out of here. Your research was worthless anyway."

Comment: Add to that he actually had three mortgages on the house.  "Everybody has three mortgages nowadays."

Comment: It is entirely possible to build a particle accelerator  on a hobbyist's budget if you are willing to put in a lot of work. Most of the cost of scientific equipment is the specialist knowledge needed to assemble and design it. Since it is generally one-off, you are paying for several man-years of work by highly paid(150k+/yr) specialists by yourself. Having built a farnsworth fusor with scrounged parts, I see no issues with them building what they describe fairly cheaply if they are willing to put in a lot of legwork to track down used/cheap parts.

Answer (score 3):

According to the film's second [official novelisation](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Richard_Mueller), the Ghostbusters were unable to salvage any of the equipment or supplies from their office at UC Columbia

> *“You‘re thinking. That’s a thinking sound you’re making. I know that sound. What do you think?”
>
>   “I don’t know. That costs money. And the ectocontainment system we have in mind will require a load of bread to capitalize. Where would we get the money?”
>
>   “Ray, trust me.”*

They had to resort to building their own customised equipment (from scratch) using the money gleaned from the three mortgages on Ray's family home.

> *Janine Melnitz was fed up. She’d never been so bored in her life. When
>   she’d first taken the job with Ghostbusters she’d assumed that it
>   would be exciting. She’d been in a TV commercial with three men who
>   were supposedly going to be catching real live ghosts. **She’d seen the
>   money pour into their building, their equipment, the bizarre ambulance
>   that Ray Stantz insisted on calling an Ectomobile.***

As to the precise value of the house, we know that one of the mortgages cost Ray approximately $18,000 per annum in interest charges alone. Assuming the other mortgages were at least as good (or better) value, that means that they borrowed more than $300k, all of which had been spent by the time their second case (at the hotel) arrived.

Comment: Why was there a second one as opposed to just one? Just curious.

Comment: @Broklynite - Ask it as a question